# Force QItemDelegate to repaint

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qitemdelegate, pyside2

I am currently trying to get custom delegate to change a color it is painting with via an external button. I currently have it working in the sense of the button will change the color the delegate draws with but the delegate does not update upon the button press, but instead updates when I move my mouse over the associated viewer.

I made a custom button for color purposes (pretty simple)

```
class ColorButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,color=None):
        super(ColorButton,self).__init__(parent)
        self.color=color

    def paintEvent(self,e):
        painter=QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        painter.fillRect(self.rect(),self.color)
        painter.end()

    def getColor(self):
        return self.color
```

I then connect the color button's pressed() signal to my delegate's updateBG function.

```
button1=ColorButton(color=QColor(0,0,0))
button1.pressed.connect(delegate.updateBG)
```

The delegate's updateBG() function simply updates a color variable within the itself.

```
def updateBG(self):
    color=self.sender().getColor()
    self.bgBrush=QBrush(color)
```

I have the paint() function just use this color when it draws a rectangle.

```
def paint(self,painter,option,index):
    painter.save()
    painter.setBrush(self.bgBrush)
    painter.drawRect(self.rect())
    painter.restore()
```

Is there a way to force a delegate to repaint? Both the update() and repaint() functions don't apply to the delegate itself. Do I have to call a repaint() on my viewer (which is QListView)? If that is the only way, is there a way to get the viewer from within the delegate? Or should I move this updateBG() function outside of the delegate class?

I am using QT5 via QT.py (effectively pyside2 or PyQt5).

Comment: I think the recommended approach is to store the information (in this case the colour) in the model (for example inside a custom user role). Then, when you update the model, the relevant signals should be fired between the model and the view to redraw the appropriate part (provided your drawing code reads the value from the model fo course!).

Comment: This would probably work but would be heavily redundant. The color change is a more global description of how the delegate draws all of the model items. If I stored it in the model, I would have to update every entry inside with the new color which would seem less efficient than just updating a single variable in the delegate. I did find a way to get things to manually update though.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realise it was a global (or close to global) colour. In that case you probably want to use stylesheets. I'm pretty sure you can access that information from the paint method and that it would be called when the style sheet is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Found I could force an update by connecting the pressed() signal to my viewer's reset function.

```
button1.pressed.connect(viewer.reset)
```

Not sure if this is the best method, but it seems to work.